# Running Ubuntu installed on other partition in VM

Tags: ubuntu, virtualbox, virtual-machine

I have two partitions on my PC, with Windows and Ubuntu systems installed. I also use VirtualBox to run a couple of virtual machines. Can I use the Ubuntu installation from my hard disk and launch it inside a VM?

If not: is a setup like this — one system that can boot both as a host OS and a guest OS — even theoretically possible in some other configuration?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the correct permissions are applied to the physical partition, it is possible with both VirtualBox and VMWare (I am unsure with KVM at the moment).  However, if you are attempting to use a Windows partition to boot back and forth between a physical partition and a VM partition, you will more than likely come across issues - specifically driver issues.